# Загрузчик ОС на Ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте, нужно написать загрузчик. Не прошу вас писать за меня, просто объясните мне его принцип работы. Например, как он загружается в память, мне до сих пор не до конца понятно.

Comment: Для лабораторной достаточно этой заметки: [создание собственного загрузчика](http://www.sysdes.ru/articles/platforms/os/_0001.html). Для серьезных вещей лучше смотреть исходники grub и т.п.

Comment: http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/hello-world-boot-loader

Answer (score 2):

Первой загружается "Программа начальной загрузки", которая находится в BIOS. После того как она проверит исправность оборудования (а возможно и не только - это зависит от самой ПНЗ) - она выбирает загрузочный диск (один из тех, что подключены к компу) и просто копирует первый сектор диска в оперативку, и передает ему управление.

По этой теме очень много полезной инфы тут: http://wasm.ru/article/260 и тут же очень хороший форум.

Comment: Для этой вашей/нашей UEFI, видимо, уже не сработает...

Comment: wasm.ru - сайта больше нет.(?)

Comment: https://wasm.in